# How can I use a private git repo with NextJS on Vercel?

Tags: git, npm, next.js, vercel

I have a private git repo of a small `React` datatable component. I've included that repo in a separate project for a headless CMS, via `npm install --save git+ssh://git@github.com/Me/datatable.git`.

Everything works fine locally, but when I published this change, the build on Vercel fails. Reading about the error led me down a rabbit hole of publishing releases, to (hopefully) create a package, which should maybe (fingers crossed) be available to Vercel somehow if I manage to find the right access key and put it in the right spot with the right configuration.

Well, that isn't working and I'm completely stuck. Note that I don't have an `npm` account, and I'd have to sign up for a monthly plan in order to list this repo privately. I got the impression that there was a way to publish it on github instead?

**Here are some more details, first is the output from Vercel:**

```
12:42:49.146    [1/4] Resolving packages...
12:42:56.576    error Command failed.
12:42:56.577    Exit code: 128
12:42:56.577    Command: git
12:42:56.577    Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads ssh://git@github.com/Me/datatable.git
12:42:56.577    Directory: /vercel/path0
12:42:56.577    Output:
12:42:56.577    Host key verification failed.
12:42:56.577    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
12:42:56.578    
12:42:56.578    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
12:42:56.578    and the repository exists.
12:42:56.578    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
12:42:56.601    Error: Command "yarn install" exited with 128
```

**Here's a snippet from package.json**:

```
...

  "repository": "git://github.com/Me/datatable.git",
  "publishConfig": {
     "@Me:registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
  },
...
```

Some research on Vercel's output led me to this page: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/quickstart#publishing-your-package

I've gotten to step 10, where it claims

> If the tests pass, then the package will be published to GitHub Packages. To test this out, navigate to the Code tab in your repository and create a new release.

Well, I created a new release, but no package magically showed up anywhere. The docs on github helpfully don't mention what to do at this point.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: The "host key verification failed" error is actually from ssh, not from Git. Check the host key on the system that is claiming that the host key is wrong: why does it not match the host key that this system is getting *from* the host that holds the Git repository in question?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently for Vercel deployment. And i created
`server_install.sh` file.

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i '' -e "s/git@bitbucket.org\/org_name\/repo_name.git#v1.0.1/git+https:\/\/$BITBUCKET_USERNAME:$BITBUCKET_PASSWORD@bitbucket.org\/org_name\/repo_name.git/g" package.json

yarn install

echo "Install successful!"
```

This code will update the private repository path in `package.json` with authentication and then run the `yarn install`.

**Note** *I prefer to use ssh key in such case. I created a script because did not found any solution for Vercel. Happy to learn if there is better approach available.*